# How can I repair an improper list in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I accidentally did (the equivalent of) the following:

```
lists:foldl(fun(X, Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, 0, List).
```

Note the not-a-list initial value for the accumulator.

This resulted in an improper list. This means that `length`, etc., don't work on it.

Given that my "equivalent of" took an hour to run, and I don't want to run it again, how do I repair my improper list?

For a simpler example of an improper list and the problem that it causes:

```
1> L = [1|[2|[3|4]]].
[1,2,3|4]
2> length(L).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  length/1
        called as length([1,2,3|4])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the "improper tail", this would be enough:

```
Fix = fun Fix([H | T]) -> [H | Fix(T)];
          Fix(T) -> [T]
      end.
```

Answer (score -1):

For the simple case I had, with non-nested improper list, where I don't want the extra item (because it should have been an empty list and doesn't mean anything), this'll do it:

```
Fix = fun F([H|T], A) when is_list(T) -> F(T, [H|A]);
          F([H|_], A) -> F([], [H|A]);
          F([], A) -> lists:reverse(A)
      end.
Fix(L, []).
```

Comment: This approach will not work with folded lists. If you try put `[[[1,[1|2]],1|2],1|[2|[3|4]]]` you can see  that the `Fix/2` function will return `[[[1,[1|2]],1|2],1,2,3]` as you can see the contents of the list are broken, plus the list still improper. P.S. I was update my answer below.

Comment: That's a nested list of improper lists. Your answer is useful for dealing with that, but it's overkill for the situation in the question.

Comment: This solution drops the "improper tail" of the input. `Fix([1, 2, 3 | 4])` would return `[1, 2, 3]`, not `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Is this really what you want?

Comment: As it happens, yes, in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible approach:

```erlang
Lister = fun L([], Acc)                -> lists:reverse(Acc);
             L([[_ | _] = H | T], Acc) -> L(T, [L(H, []) | Acc]);
             L([[] | T], Acc)          -> L(T, Acc);
             L([H | T], Acc)           -> L(T, [H | Acc]);
             L(X, Acc)                 -> L([], [X | Acc])
         end.

L = [[[1,[1|2]],1|2],1|[2|[3|4]]].

Lister(L, []).
% output [[[1,[1,2]],1,2],1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: That doesn't deal with *improper* lists. Try feeding it `[1|[2|[3|4]]]`

Answer (score -3):

you must use list for ACC

```erlang
lists:foldl(fun(X, Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, 0, [1,2,3]).
```

result => [3,2,1|0]
but if you use [0] for ACC argument in lists:foldl/3 function like bellow

```erlang
lists:foldl(fun(X, Acc) -> [X|Acc] end, [0], [1,2,3]).
```

result => [3,2,1,0]

Comment: Yes. I know. I didn't. The question is _how to repair an improper list_.